# Apollo (react-apollo): Force a re-query even if query didn't change

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I have a GraphQL end-point that returns a random name each time it is queried.

It seems that Apollo's Query object won't re-query if the query itself doesn't change. Here is a snippet of the code:

```js
class RandomName extends React.Component {
render() {
  const query = gql`
   query name($gender: String, $top: Int) {
    name(gender: $gender, top: $top) {
     firstName
     gender
     surname
    }
   }
  `;
  return (
   <Query
    query={query}
    variables={{ gender: this.props.gender, top: this.props.top }}
    fetchPolicy="network-only"
   >
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
         if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
     if (error) return <p>Error</p>;
          return <p>{name.firstName} {name.surname}</p>
        }}
      </Query>
  }
}
```

If the gender or top variables change, the query will get re-run, but if I have a button that forces a re-query, it won't re-run the query if the query is exactly the same as the last time it ran. I read the docs and this seems to be proper behavior.

Here is code that is inside the parent component:

```js
onClick() {
  this.setState({
   sendGender: this.state.currentGender,
   sendTop: this.state.currentTop,
  });
  this.forceUpdate();
}

render() {
<Button onClick={() => this.onClick()}>Get Name</Button>
}
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround. If I move the button to be in the Query component, I can use the refetch() function. I still need to be able to change the query if my parent object has changed, though, so I can pass a function from my parent object to return its state:

```js
< Query
query = {
  query
}
variables = {
  {
    gender: this.props.gender,
    top: this.props.top
  }
}
fetchPolicy = "network-only" >
  {
    ({
      loading,
      error,
      data,
      refetch
    }) => {
      // Not shown: dealing with query
      // New button here...
      <button
        onClick = {() => {
            refetch(this.props.refresh());
          }
        }>
        Reload
      </button>
```

Then in the parent component, here is the refresh() function that gets passed:

```js
onRefresh() {
  return { gender: this.state.currentGender, top: this.state.currentTop };
}
```